# Shadow artefacts when rendering with bevel-modification

Tags: modeling, rendering, modifiers, geometry, bevel

When rendering with bevel-modification some parts appear non-beveled on the shadow side of the object.
This doesn't appear when using the "manual method", ctrl-b. File attached: [spraycover.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HArDguNxbCPPSUEkucnS3iXqd3JQhnYg/view?usp=sharing)

What is going on, how can I prevent this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you have duplicate geometry, or that the corners are made up of 2 unconnected faces. To clean up your mesh, you can try `Mesh > Clean Up > Merge by Distance`. This will "snap together" all vertices that are within a certain distance of each other.

If this doesn't solve your problem, you might have to manually inspect the faulty areas of the mesh. Select the  vertex you are having issues with, and move it out of the way to see what's going on. This might help you understand how the mesh is connected, and what is causing the problems.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Double vertices is a major cause of troubles and are on my troubleshooting list :)
I'll also acknowledge your proposal of manual inspection.

Answer (score 1):

In short - you have to **change Profile Shape to 0.5**

---

With Segment = 1 it's fine ...

[image]

... but appears on 2 segments. Why?

[image]

Because with 2 segments the beveled edge is split onto two faces and since your *Profile* *Shape* is set to 1 in generates back angle 90deg and only shading (Normals) stay smooth. There is still enabled Auto Smooth in Data Properties driven by modifier that seems to be confused - shade it smooth or flat? You can check that if you *Apply* modifier to see topology ...

[image]

... if you go to *Data Properties* > **Geometry Data** and hit *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* it becomes fixed.

[image]

Anyway, back to your issue. What you have to do is to **change Profile Shape to 0.5** so the bevel create interpolation between those two faces - round it.

[image]

Comment: Excellent! This solved my problem and your thorough and comprehensive explanation demystified the matter for me (also I have noticed the phenomena when changing step 1 to 2 in segments). Thanks alot.